# How to use docker to create a minimal live ISO that runs docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, live-cd

I'm looking to create a very lightweight live ISO of ubuntu that runs docker. I'd like to be able to create this custom live ISO using a docker container to handle provisioning and all setup steps. Basically, I want to run a Dockerfile that after building/running, outputs a live ISO I could boot from that is setup to run docker within it.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [FAI - Fully Automatic Installation](http://fai-project.org/) to create an ISO that installs and configure Ubuntu and Docker.

I have created a Docker image (ricardobranco/fai:4.3.3) to create these ISO's.  The code at GitHub: https://github.com/ricardobranco777/fai

There are scripts to create the mirror, another to validate it, and to create the ISO.  I've just committed a simple FAI config that I use to create ISO's to the faiconfig folder in my GitHub repo

PD: I haven't had success with FAI 5.x and Ubuntu 16 (for some unknown reason at the time).  For this reason I use 4.3.3.  The maintainer was kind enough to keep the 4.3.3 Debian packages in the FAI repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have been working with your repo to see if it suits my needs. I'm currently stuck on the hostname argument of fai-mirror.sh returning unknown host. What is a simple input that would work here?

Comment: The available hosts are defined on faiconfig/class/50-host-classes.   The only host is "docker".  Change it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

boot2docker can be considered as a minimal ISO that runs docker:
https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker